# Azure - Does Microsoft azure support SFTP

Tags: azure, sftp

I'm looking into setting up SFTP on an Azure VM.
All the MS support articles I'm seeing ask that we install a vm template that uses Azure Files Shares instead.
I also don't see an option for SFTP under the network security groups inbound rules.
Does Microsoft currently support SFTP?
Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: There are pre-configured options made by 3rd parties. If you go here: https://portal.azure.com/#create/hub then search "FTP"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Azure Files (which supports SMB, NFSv3 and NFSv4 protocols) is more prevalent than support for SFTP. It is however present in some places such as [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp), [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh) and [FTP/S on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal), etc.

There are [third](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/thorntechnologiesllc.sftpgateway?tab=overview) [party](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/filemagellc.filemage-gateway-vm-win?tab=overview) products on the Azure Marketplace that can setup SFTP gateways as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Update: Meanwhile Azure Blob Storage supports SFTP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support